# Swift: textView method "scrollRangeToVisible" not working after changing UI Text View size in storyboard?

Tags: swift, textview, uitextview

I'm new to swift. When my UItextView is filled up, I would like to have my UItextView to automatically scroll to what I have typed (bottom of UItextView).

I used scrollRangeToVisible and it had worked for the first time. However, after I changed the UItextView UI Size to be smaller, it hasn't been working ever since.

This is the code I have now.

```
    let range = NSMakeRange(textView.text.count - 1, 0)
    textView.scrollRangeToVisible(range)
```

The behavior seems weird to me.
First, it will not automatically scroll to the bottom, then, after I manually scrolled it to the bottom and type letters to the UItextView, it will pop up a blank page like this:
[Random blank pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGvQF.png)
.Then type letters again it will be scrolled to the bottom for once:
 [Scrolled to bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQZW2.png)
.Then type again it will have larger bank pop up:
[Larger random blank pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FJWX.png)
.Type again the blank becomes even larger:
[Blank pop up filled up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRUO1.png)
.Then type again the scroll down to bottom works for once again:
[Scroll to bottom works again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOP6j.png)
. After keep typing, this will finally work, the UItextView will scroll to the very bottom when typing a new line.
It's been a very weird problem and I have seen some resources saying emoji will cause problem for "scrollRangeToVisible". 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try scrolling to where your caret is:

```
textView.scrollRangeToVisible(textView.selectedRange)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it still have the problem I described above. It will randomly jump out a blank page.

Comment: Make sure `textView.isScrollEnabled = true`

Comment: Do you see the same issue without emojis (just letters)?

Comment: I would try `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO` and see if it helps.